# Show Microsoft Onedrive shared folders on Windows Desktop

Tags: windows, onedrive, shared-folders

How do I get Microsoft OneDrive shared folders to show on the Windows Desktop?

The shared folder that is shared with me can only be accessed online.

Answer (score 5):

This is possible in classic view version of one drive.

1. Click on the "Return to classic One Drive" option on the bottom left corner when accessing one drive online.
2. This will make the "Sync" option visible for the shared folders.
3. Sync it to get it downloaded on local copy of one drive.

Comment: This is the correct answer!

Comment: Agree, this is the only real solution.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

I recently found instructions on Microsoft's website entitled [Add and sync shared folders to OneDrive](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-and-sync-shared-folders-to-OneDrive-8a63cd47-1526-4cd8-bd09-ee3f9bfc1504) and they worked for me:

> Sign in to OneDrive on your browser.
>
> 1. In the OneDrive navigation pane, under **OneDrive**, click **Shared**. Folders you can add to your OneDrive are marked **Can edit**.
> 2. Find the folder you want to add, and click the circle in the folder's tile to select it.
> 3. Click **Add to my OneDrive**. Or, if you prefer, you can right-click the folder and then click **Add to my OneDrive**.

You don't get to pick where the folder is stored locally, however.  It will be stored in directly in your OneDrive folder as a peer to your Documents folder but that's an acceptable trade-off for me; at least I can sync the files locally.

Answer (score 1):

It seems possible, but with some limitation, you need to have edit permission on the folder shared with you and need to enable the synchronization manually which is not enable by default;

source: https://www.eduhk.hk/ocio/content/faq-how-sync-shared-me-onedrive-business-folders-your-local-computer

Procedures:

- Login Office 365 portal.
- Browse to your OneDrive for Business. (At the top bar, select the Office 365 app launcher icon, and then select OneDrive.)
- Click “Shared with me”, from the left panel.
- Click on the folder you want to sync to your computer.
- Click “Sync”.
- Follow the prompts to complete the process.
- This folder will show up on your computer under the path `C:\Users\{login user name}\SharePoint\`.

Comment: Is it possible to move the location of the folder that is shared with you, specifically the location on your end?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using personal Microsoft account with OneDrive, we can do the following steps to sync shared folders (It requires "can Edit" permission) in OneDrive desktop app:

1. Sign in [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/) with your Microsoft Account (not work or school Office 365 account).
2. In the OneDrive navigation pane, expand OneDrive, click **Shared**. Select the folders you want to add to your OneDrive which are marked **Can edit**.
3. Click **Add to my OneDrive**. Or, if you prefer, you can right-click the folder and then click Add to my OneDrive.

If you are using Office 365 OneDrive for Business account and the shared folder is also shared by another Office 365 OneDrive for Business account, you can select the folder under “**shared with me**” section and click **Sync** to sync it.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you have the permission to edit the shared folders or not, you can directly right-click on it and select "Download" to download it to your computer. Thus, you can edit them as you like. If you want your edits both stored on local and online OneDrive, you can either move the downloaded folder to your local OneDrive folder to make it synced to cloud, or, reupload the downloaded folder to your OneDrive cloud and make it synced back to local.